# Accent remains separated in NSTextView while typing

Tags: cocoa, diacritics, nstextview

I use NSTextView in my Cocoa app. I press Option-E, the text view displays an acute accent in a yellow highlight box, indicating that it is marked text, rather than final input. When the I type the next character, the text view must display it as a single accented character but it doesn't. For example [image] 
Why?

UPDATE: here are my steps:
[image]

Comment: In my own app that uses NSTextView, if I click option-E twice, you'll get your single accent character. Do you only want to have an accute accent for option-C instead of the functionality that the standard NSTextView class provides?

Comment: I don't want that an extra accent character remains. I updated my question.

Comment: This is an unmodified `NSTextView`? Not a subclass? No categories on `NSTextView` in your program?

Comment: This happened to me as a result of overriding `[insertText:]`, when subclassing `NSTextView`